# Create a web page in odoo 8

Tags: templates, web, odoo-8

I create a web page in odoo 8,

I created a template in `/mymodule/views/my_template.xml`

```
 <template id="dms_web_client.webclient_bootstrap1" name="FTP server Webclient">
     <t t-call="website.layout">
         <a id="create_new_directory" href="#" data-action="new_dir">New Directory</a>
     </t>

 </template>
```

When I click on a link `New Directory` I need to open up a pop up with a text box and file browse and save & cancel button. Like create a new page in website module. 
I don't know what to do next. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interact with other models within your module (or even Odoo in general), you're probably going to want to create a controller, which can contain python code and allow your web page to interact with models. On a simple level, a controller can go in your main folder (ie /mymodule/my_template_controller.py) and be declared in your **init**.py file (import my_template_controller). You can then set a route that matches your template id and create forms that post to the controller, allowing python code to be run and models to be interacted with. That can allow you to have your file browse and save and cancel button.

As far as the front end, you can use html, css, and Javascript like any normal website and they can be declared via normal links in the page header.

Odoo does have some documentation, but it is pretty poor, unfortunately. It took  me a long time to decipher how to fully build a web application within it. However, it works great once you figure it out and it generally follows the guidelines of any other model/controller/view application.

http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/website.html
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/http.html